# difference between tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy() vs "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" as loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm implementing a multi class classification problem,

1. when I'm using my loss as **tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()**, I'm getting very less accuracy

```
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=["accuracy"])
```

2. And when I use loss as **"sparse_categorical_crossentropy"**, I'm getting much higher accuracy

```
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

- Does this have to do with batch size?
- How to get same results as "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" using custom loss layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because when you use

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
```

metrics should

```
"sparse_categorical_accuracy" not "accuracy"
```